# How to refresh fonts list while application is running?

Tags: c#, fonts

In my application I check if some font is installed.

If not, than I extract this font file from resources to temp folder and I start process with this file path as an argument - it opens windows fonts view.

In this system font view I install font, and in application I get fonts list once again - and still list does not contain this font.

After application restart, list contains this font.

Is there a way to refresh/reload font list while application is working?

```
        private void BtnInstallFontIfNotPrsent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool fontPresent = false;
            InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < fonts.Families.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fonts.Families[i].Name.Equals("Code 128")) fontPresent = true;
            }

            // fontPresent is false

            if (!fontPresent)
            {
                string fontsfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
                string tempFolderPath = Path.GetTempPath();
                string randomFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "") + ".ttf";
                string randomFilePatch = Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, randomFileName);
                File.WriteAllBytes(randomFilePatch, Resources.Code_128);
                Process.Start(randomFilePatch);
                // font instalation
            }
        }

        private void BtnCheckIfFontIsNowPresent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool fontPresent = false;
            InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < fonts.Families.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fonts.Families[i].Name.Equals("Code 128")) fontPresent = true;
            }

            // fontPresent still false
        }
```

More simple:

My C# code simply opens font with windows fontview.exe.

My code does not install font.

Font is installed manually through fontview.exe.

[image]

If I open notepad, and I install font while notepad is working, after installation font is accesible in notepad instantly without restarting it.

In my application not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding font have two step.you probably missed the second step :
Step 1, call AddFontResource and pass it the file name to the font. 
step 2, do a SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0) to tell all processes that we loaded the font.

This function installs the font only for the current session. When the system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in the registry. the registry key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts